# Best way to persist an Array of Custom Objects in Swift on iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nscoder

My current solution to this problem is creating a class that implements `NSObject` and `NSCoder` and using that to encode and decode my `Array` of `Plant Objects` (Plant consists of two `strings` and a `UIImage`).  It seems unnecessary that I have to create a `class` just so that I can use `NSCoder` to save an `array`.  Is there a better way of doing this?

EDIT:  To be clear, the `plant class` is NOT implementing `NSCoder`.  It is simply an `NSObject`.  I have a separate `class` (a `singleton`, if you will), that I encode and decode when the app closes and begins.  That `singleton`, contains my `Array` of `Plants`.

EDIT:  Plant Class

```
public class Plant: NSObject {
    private var name: String
    private var waterFrequency: Int
    private var date: Date
    private var img: UIImage
    private let dFormat = DateFormatter()

    public init(n: String, wF: Int) {
        self.name = n
        self.waterFrequency = wF
        self.date = Date();
        dFormat.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    }
}
```

Singleton

```
public class Singleton: NSCoder {
    private static var myPlantList: [Plant] {
        get {
            return myPlantList
        } set(pL) {
        self.myPlantList = pL
        }
    }

    private override init(pL: [Plant]){
        //init
    }

    required convenience init?(coder? aDecoder: NSCoder){
        //Decode
    }
}
```

Comment: But you're not creating a class (`Plant`) just to save the array. You have a class because using a class is the proper way (actually a `struct` is probably better) to organize your two strings and image together.

Comment: @rmaddy check edit.  Plant is not implementing NSCoder.  I have a seperate class just for encoding and decoding the array of Plants.

Comment: Perhaps if you showed some relevant code and clarified what issues you are having, it would be easier to help.

Comment: @rmaddy Added code.  I didn't have the Singleton Class finished, so I didn't know if it would be much help, but this should clarify what i'm trying to do.